# Crash report is not showing when an android app is launched through Real Device?

Tags: crittercism

We launched one android  demo app(Hello World) on a real device.One Runtime exception has been written in code in order to crash the app.Crashes showing in crittercism are not the latest crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my proposed solution:
Assuming all other configuration is correct:

1. Make sure you are building in release mode (so that Pro Guard will generate the mapping.txt file.
2. Upload your mapping.txt file to Crittercism so that you may symbolicate.

Further Proguard Symbolication details are provided [here](http://docs.crittercism.com/android/android.html#configuring-proguard-symbolication).